# Getting database error when calling CateogoryService method

Tags: database, php, services

I have a PHP file in the `public_html` titled `categories.php` with the following code:

```
namespace Craft;
$craft = require '../craft/app/bootstrap.php';     
$categories = $craft->categories->allGroupIds();
```

Running this script results in the following message:

```
Error error
Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php.
```

My `craft/config/db.php` file looks like this.

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    ),
    'live' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
    ),
    'staging' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'DB_USER',
        'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'database' => 'DB_NAME',
    ),
    'dev' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'DB_NAME',
    ),
);
```

I'm not having database trouble anywhere else, only when I try to call any CategoriesService methods. Is there something that I'm failing to understand here?

**Solution:**

The CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT constant was being set in public_html/index.php, so my craft/config/db.php file could not choose the correct database credentials. The issue was resolved by setting the constant to 'dev' in my categories.php file, like below.

```
namespace Craft;
define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'dev');
$craft = require '../craft/app/bootstrap.php';
$categories = $craft->categories->allGroupIds();
```

Comment: The above code works for me in the Happy Lager example site, except the `allGroupIds()` should be `allGroupIds`, as this is a property and not a method. That doesn't explain the database error, though. Is your `public` directory next to your `craft` directory on the filesystem?

Comment: Yes, it sits right next to the craft folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how you're defining the `'live'`, `'staging'` and `'dev'` keys for the multi-environment config, but most likely you just need to explicitly set the [`CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT`](https://craftcms.com/docs/php-constants#craft-environment) PHP constant in your `categories.php` file to tell Craft which database credentials to choose.